# how to get true/false output when using integer parameter name with return

Tags: android, string, kotlin, integer, boolean

**To-do**

> Adjust the function below with the code to check whether the parameter number is an even number
>
> ```
> fun isEvenNumber(number: int) = false
> ```

```
fun isEvenNumber(number: int): Boolean {
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
      return true
   } else {
      return false
   }
}
```

What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Who says it's wrong? You can write it in a more compact way but (without compiling) I can't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer isn't wrong. It's just not elegant and compact.

You can shrink down your code and just return `number % 2 == 0` directly without using an if statement and returning `true` and `false`.